# Which is scalable? Simple CRUD Webapp vs Webapp talking to a REST service

Tags: java, scala, scalability, playframework

I think the title says it clearly. I am no scalability guru. I am on the verge of creating a web application which needs to scale to large data sets and possibly many (wont exaggerate here, lets say thousands of) concurrent users.

`MongoDB` is the data repository and i am torn between writing a simple `Play!` webapp talking to `MongoDB` versus `Play!` app talking to a REST service app (in Scala) which does the heavy lifting of all business logic and persistence.

Part of me thinks that having the business logic wrapped as a service is future proof and allows deploying just the webapp in multiple nodes (scaling). I come from Java EE stack and Play! is a rebel in java web frameworks. This approach assures me that i can move away from Play! if needed.

Part of me also thinks that Play! app + Scala service app is additional complexity and mayn't be fruitful in the long run.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

NOTE: I am a newbie to Scala, MongoDB and Play!. Pardon me if my question was silly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scalability is an engineering art. Which means that you have lots of parameters and apply your experience to specific values of these parameters to come to a solution. So general advice, without more specific data about your problem, is hard.

Having said that, from experience, some general advice:

- Keep your application as clean and simple as possible. This allows you to keep your options open. In your case, start with a simple Play app. Concentrate on clean code so you can easily rework what you have into a different architectural model (with clean code, that's simpler than you'd think :-))
- Measure, not guess, where the bottlenecks are. It's simple enough to flood a server with requests. Use profiling, memory dumps, whatever, to pinpoint your bottleneck in scalability.

Only then, with a working app in hand (which you could launch early with) and data on where your scaling bottlenecks are, you can make decisions on what to split off in (horizontally scalable) services.

On the outset, services look nice and scalable, but they often get you in an early mess - services need to communicate with each other, so you start introducing messaging, etcetera. Keep it simple, measure, optimize.

Comment: I do agree that service layer adds a bit of complexity, but what i dont completely agree is that the fact that this layer can be added later on as the need arises. But thanks for the tip. Simplicity is the way to go.

Comment: Trust me - you can. Clean code will have natural internal interfaces, and remoting these into a service is usually quite easy. Clean code wins, always :)

Answer (score 2):

The question does not appear to be silly . For me encapsulating your data access behind the rest layer does not directly improve the scalability of the application.(significantly, ofcourse, there is the server that can perform http caching and handle request queues etc.., but from your description, your application looks small enough). You can achieve similar scalability without the Rest layer. But having said that, the Service layer could have a indirect impact.

First it makes your application cleaner. (UI Talking to db is messy.). It helps make the application maintainable. (Multi folds). Rest layer could provide you with middle tier that you may need in your application. Also a correctly designed Rest Layer will have to be Resource Driven . In my experience  a Resource Driven Architecture is a good middle ground between ease of implementation and highly scalable design.

So I strongly suggest that you use the Service layer (Rest is the way to go :) ), but scalability in itself cannot justify the decision.

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, i should be adding the service layer to keep the code clean and not add it for scaling.. is that a correct interpretation of your answer?

Comment: Scalability should not be the primary reason for adding the service layer. There are other more compelling reason for that. Adding the layer will help the scalability but considering the scale of your application, I was of opinion that the improvement would not be very significant.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the service between the UI and data source encapsulates the data source, so the UI need not know the details of how data is persisted.  It also prevents the UI from reaching directly into the data source.  This allows the service to authenticate, authorize, validate, bind, and perform biz logic as needed.

The downside is a slight speed bump for the app.

I'd say that adding the service has a small cost and a big upside.  I'd vote for that.

Comment: +1 for general suggestion. Could you please also describe the effect on scalability.. I based my answer mainly based on the scale of the application, but I would like to hear other opinions.

Comment: Does adding a service layer help in scaling? Meaning, one service app and multiple instances of webapp, is this architecture prevalent in the real world>

Answer (score 1):

The answer, as usual, is. It depends.
If there is some heavy-lifting involved and some business logic: Yup, that is best put into its own layer and if you add a RESTful interface to it, you can serve that up to whatever front-end technology you want.

Nowadays, people are often not bothering with having a separate web app layer, but serve the data via AJAX directly to the client.

You might consider adding a layer, if you either need to maintain a lot of user session state or have an opportunity to cache data on the presentation layer. There are more reasons why you would want a presentation layer, for example, serving out different presentations to different devices/clients.

Don't just add layers for complexities sake, though.

I might add that you should try to employ the HATEOAS principle. That will ease things significantly when scaling out the solution.